# How can I convert a numpy object to a regular python list?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a variable `x` that has a `dtype` of `float32`, which contains:

```
[[0. .... 0.]
 [0. .... 0.]
 [0. .... 0.]
 [0. .... 0.]]
```

I have another variable `y` that has a `dtype` of `object`, which contains:

```
[array([0., ..., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)
 array([0., ..., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)
 array([0., ..., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)
 array([0., ..., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)]
```

That's after I do `y = np.array(y)`

I need to convert `y` to match the same type and structure of `x`. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: have you tried something as simple as `np.array(y)`?

Comment: Yup, I tried that and it's an `object`

Comment: Could you add more info (a *mcve*)? How do you create the 2 objects?

Comment: What's the `shape` of each of those arrays within `y`?  `[i.shape() for i in y]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just stack the arrays:

```
y = np.stack(y)
```

If you want to convert to a list you can do:

```
y.tolist()
```

Note that this will also convert the Numpy data types (`np.float32` in your case) to Python internal data types (`float`).

Comment: This will work if the elements of `y` are all the same shape.  And raises an error if they aren't.  The underlying question is why is `y` object dtype?  Was it intentionally constructed that way, or is that a result of unintential mixed shapes?

Answer (score 1):

Using a list comprehension should do it..

```
x = [np.array([1,2,3]),np.array([4,5,6])]
y = [list(i) for i in x]
print(y)
```